# How to change the order of a <p> element with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```html
  <?php
 // Create database connection
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image_upload");

  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    //$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

    // image file directory
    //$target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image_text) VALUES ('$image_text')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    /*if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
      $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
      $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }*/
  }

  if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $sqldelete = "DELETE FROM images WHERE id_test=0";
    mysqli_query($db, $sqldelete);
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `images`");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.16/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
    <title>Image Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <?php
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<div id='img_div'>";
            echo "<p>".$row['image_text']."</p>";
          echo "</div>";
        }
      ?>
      <form method="POST" action="testupload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
        <!--<div>
          <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>-->
        <div>
          <textarea 
            id="text" 
            cols="40" 
            rows="4" 
            name="image_text" 
            placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
          <button type="submit" name="delete">DELETE</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#text').summernote();
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Well first of all, sorry for my english (which is not terrible but not perfect). It's my first subject so please be indulgent. I'm a beginner in PHP.

Okay my problem is the following:

I got a code in PHP, in which i'm adding data (text) to MySQL data base (for exemple some random text).

In order to make it work, when i'm clicking on the button, it's creating a `div` element, with a `p` element and finally the text submitted. When I'm adding another one it's going under (beacuase it's create on the following line) [maybe you will understand with a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o07c2.png).

So my question is, can I make it in a different order (like test2: the most recent above the test1 (you have to see the picture to understand)? Or can I display it with another way?

Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to make it clear...

The code isn't from me, I took it from a tutorial on youtube [here is the part of the code when it's displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XngQB.png) and [here the main part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFquV.png) (with sql and everithing). (don't interest you to the delete part)

Thanks a lot and sorry if it's so obvious for you I tried a lot before sending a message but I've never seen any response to a similar problem... If things are unclear pls tell me :)

Have a nice day/night...

jQuery and summer note tags added.

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not images.

Comment: it is okay now?

Comment: Your problems are not with `php`. The new DOM element is created with the javascript libraries loaded in your header: `jQuery` and `summernote`. The latter is a mystery to me, and so I leave this to someone familiar with `summernote`. I suspect that you should be looking at the jQuery `.before` method.

Comment: Well first of all thanks for your quick response! summernote is a WYSIWYG editor (for the textarea and without it's teh same problem but i will give a try with the jQuery even if I don't know anithing of it. Thanks!

Comment: It would be something like: `$('#addItem').before(newItem);` where `newItem` represents a string of the new `html`. I have found this works better if this `html` has no line breaks in the code.

Comment: Why not query in descending order? Something like `SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id DESC` (I'm guessing you have an ID column on your table)

Comment: Thanks a lot every one it's now working with the Camilo response... I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you have an `id` column on your table, you can simple query results in reverse order:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY id DESC")
```

Btw, I recommend you using [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of `mysqli`.

Comment: And I don't know a lot about PDO but i will learn thanks a lot again...